# Why flowlayoutPanel is extending horizontally?

Tags: c#, flowlayoutpanel

I have set this flowLayoutPanel, the controls inside arrange well, till the last arrives to the bottom border of the panel, then the controls start arranging on the right side (forming another column) keepping the vertical flow. I just want one column.

```
this.panel.Anchor = 
((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)
(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top |
System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)| System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
this.panel.AutoScroll = true;
this.panel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;          
this.panel.FlowDirection = System.Windows.Forms.FlowDirection.TopDown;
this.panel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 184);
this.panel.Name = "myPanel";
this.panel.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
this.panel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 371);
this.panel.TabIndex = 9;
```

Comment: Because it can.  Its job is to not waste space and avoid showing scrollbars.  Consider making it's Width less.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

`this.panel.FlowDirection = System.Windows.Forms.FlowDirection.LeftToRight;`

instead of

`this.panel.FlowDirection = System.Windows.Forms.FlowDirection.TopDown;`

if you want only one column than please add below code to your application just after control added to your flowlayoutpanel

`this.panel.SetFlowBreak(<<YOUR_ADDED_CONTROL_NAME>>, true);`

Example

```
Button btn1 = new Button();
btn1.Text = "TEST";
btn1.Height = 30;
btn1.Width = 100;

this.panel.Controls.Add(btn1);
this.panel.SetFlowBreak(btn1, true);
```